# how can i horizontally center this div with sensitive javascript in it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

on [this webpage](http://whitewashed.richiesiegel.com/)  if you scroll down to the first inline image, i have a before/after javascript slider happening.

however, the normal centering options don't seem to be working for me and end up breaking the slider. any help would be appreciate.

HTML:

```
<div class="before_after_slider">
    <div class="photo">
    <div class="after">
    <img src="center_before.jpg" width="1000px" height="600px"  alt="after" />
    </div>
    <div class="before">
    <img src="center_after.jpg" width="1000px" height="600px" alt="before" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
    <p>Roll over the photo with your cursor to see the before/after images. </p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.before_after_slider {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 55%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  & > * {
    position: relative;
  }
}

.after {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width:1000px;
  height:600px;
}

.caption {
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 140%;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 55%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with this. Like the outer containers have a width less than the inner elements.
But for now you can try this.

```
.before_after_slider{
width:1000px;
}
```

same as your images